# Capistrano: Override shared_dir variable

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

First off, very new to Capistrano, so excuse my newbness.

I am deploying a CodeIgniter application of which I have a data folder that lives outside the current web directory that I am trying to symlink to. This is what I have used to create the symlink

```
set :shared_dir, %w(/var/www/website/)
set :linked_dirs, %w{43b621acdfc9523443f27b7767e}
```

This is the result of the deployed application

```
43b621acdfc9523443f27b7767e -> /var/www/website/shared/43b621acdfc9523443f27b7767e
```

My goal is to override the shared_dir variable to generate a symlink of

```
/var/www/website/43b621acdfc9523443f27b7767e
```

I am using Capistrano 3. Any insight greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an specific task to take care of creating and updating the symlink from anywhere in your application to anywhere in your system on each deploy. For example:

```
namespace :terminal do
  task :link_external_dir, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    capifony_pretty_print '--> Generating soft link with external_example_dir'
    run "sharedWebDir=#{shared_path}/web; cd $sharedWebDir; if [ -d $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir -o -f $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir ]; then rm -rf $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir; fi; if [ ! -L $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir ]; then ln -s /srv/example/vhost/external_example_dir $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir; fi;"
    capifony_puts_ok
  end
  task :rm_shared_example_dir, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    capifony_pretty_print '--> Removing sharedDir/internal_example_dir symlink'
    run "sharedWebDir=#{shared_path}/internal_example_dir; if [ -L $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir ]; then rm $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir; fi;"
    capifony_puts_ok
  end
end
```

Now call each function on each deploy:

```
before "deploy", "terminal:rm_shared_example_dir"
after  "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
after  "deploy", "terminal:link_external_dir"
```

What we are trying to accomplish is:

1.Before Deploy, remove the file from your main sharedDir that links to your external dir.

```
REMOVE
/var/www/website/shared/externalDir -> /srv/example/vhost/external_example_dir
```

2.Deploy your app.

3.Generate the custom symlink again.

```
ln -s /srv/example/vhost/external_example_dir $sharedWebDir/internal_example_dir
```